# Where does gnome-contacts application store its data?

Tags: 13.04, contacts

Looks like Ubuntu 13.04 added gnome-contacts application. Its pretty useless or its older version which is shipped, I can't even delete contacts I have added. My question is where does it store its data?

Comment: Are you using a *local address book* setting?

Comment: @Lucio yes, using _local address book_ setting.

Answer (score 2):

Gnome-Contacts uses `evolution-data-server` by default. So any contact created in gnome-contacts can be also be found in `Personal` address-book of evolution-contacts.

The default contact list located in `~/.local/share/evolution/addressbook/system`.

If you can't delete a contact just delete it from evolution.